# Will Quantum Computing Make Mining More Efficient Then Staking?

Tags: untagged

We all hear about cracking codes with quantum computing and who encryption standard will have to change to protect blockchains, but what about quantum mining?

Will mining on quantum computers make the energy consumption of protocols like Bitcoin lessen? If so then to what extent? Will it stop being an advantage Cardano has over Bitcoin or not?

Answer (score 1):

No, PoW mining is still far more energy intensive than PoS.

PoW is always an arms race. If someone came up with a new more efficient BTC mining ASIC (completely ignoring the quantum computing part of the question) that was widely available, the same amount of energy would be used by the BTC network because that is the amount of energy available. The BTC network hash rate would however increase.

Answer (score 0):

Proof of Work is built to be inefficient, in the sense that the protocol increases the "difficulty"  of mining if technology get's better. Its security properties depend on it being difficult to mine.

If it were the case that quantum computing made mining much more efficient, than either Bitcoin would have to change the way "mining" works (making it quantum-resistant) or it would become unsafe and lose its value.